# viewDidAppear called repeatedly

Tags: iphone

I'm working on an app that displays a randomly chosen image that changes upon touch,
and I'm presenting a modal view from viewDidAppear, which works as menu.

Apparently, whenever new image is loaded on main view,
viewDidAppear is repeatedly called, so the menu modal view keeps popping up.
The reason that I put presentModalView in viewDidAppear is because the modal view has to come up at the very beginning before main view, not by a touch-trigger from main view.
I've tried presenting modal view elsewhere, but didn't really work.

any suggestion?

following is my viewDidAppear on main view,
but there's not much information from this..

```
 -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
NSLog(@"viewDidAppear");
[self presentModalViewController:modalView animated:YES];
}
```

my app constantly reloads the random image on every touch.

Comment: post your viewDidAppear method

Comment: Are all the -viewDidAppear calls being called on the same object, or on multiple instances of an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property to your UIView subclass is initialised to false in your init method...

```
@interface RandomImageView : UIView {
    BOOL hasPresentedModalMenuView
}

@property(assign) BOOL hasPresentedModalMenuView;
```

Then in your viewDidAppear method check to see if the property is false.  If so, present the view and set the property to TRUE.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear {
    if (!self.hasPresentedModalMenuView) {
        // Present view.....
        .....
        self.hasPresentedModalMenuView = TRUE;  
    }
}
```

That will prevent your modal menu view being displayed multiple times.

Comment: this is some kind of hacking, you have to discover the real reason why you get multiple viewDidAppear calls. And btw it is not necessary to add property (and even wrong). Cause this is an internal ivar, that is used only inside class and should not be exposed.

Comment: It's hard to discover the real reason without an extract of code.

As for the use of properties, I agree in principle.  But it doesn't seem to be common convention.  A lot of developers seem to use properties for internal fields to maintain calling semantics across all class members and reduce the risk of funky memory management bugs.

Comment: properties should be added only for public members. as for hasPresentedModalMenuView - it is boolean. what memory bugs could it produce?

Comment: I'm calling the modal view from the viewDidAppear of main view, so putting self.hasPresentedModalMenuView gives "Request for member 'hasPresentedModalView' in something not a structure or union' error

Comment: i've previously tried setting up a similar flag, but then from the second call, the app just terminates instead of going on

Answer (score 2):

viewDidAppear is called when your app starts. Then you display a modal view, which makes your view disappear. When the modal view goes away, your view reappears so you get viewDidAppear called again. Lather, rinse, repeat.

It sounds like you want to set a flag on your object so you can ignore the subsequent viewDidAppear calls.

Comment: "viewDidAppear is called when your app starts" isn't a very accurate statement. viewDidAppear is called on a view controller when that view controller's view was added to a window. Check out the docs for UIViewController.

Comment: @occulus: I felt it better to actually answer CosmicRabbitMediaInc's question rather than go into the exact details of the chain of events that begins with the app starting and ends with viewDidAppear getting called.